In a gazebo or under a gazebo?
Do you say that someone is in a gazebo or under a gazebo?
What I find confusing is that a gazebo is a partly enclosed structure with a railing, so that's why I am confused as to which preposition to use.

Both are possible. in is more common.  So you can choose to emphasize the protection the roof offers or the sense of enclosure.

Where's John? He's in the gazebo, garden, garage, but"on the porch or deck. Spaces with roofs is in. It is not enclosed at all, really. But it does have a roof, ergo, in not under.
